# Swift Check Dynamic Type of Array of Objects

Tags: swift

I've an array of objects `array: [AnyObject]` and want to check their dynamic type against an array of classes how can I do that?

```
let array: [AnyObject] = ["hi", true, 12]
```

The above array is an example. I want it to work with any types passed for the array.
I expect to have another array of types to check against. But I don't know how to declare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep `Any` instances and compare for `Any.Type` types with the `==` operator. Example based on the code in @lassej answer:

```
let array: [Any] = [UIView(), "hellow", 12, true]
let types: [(Any.Type, String)] = [
    (UIView.self, "UIView"),
    (String.self, "String"),
    (Int.self, "Integer")
]

anyLoop: for any in array {
    for (type, name) in types {
        if any.dynamicType == type {
            print( "type: \(name)")
            continue anyLoop
        }
    }
    print( "unknown type: \(any.dynamicType)")
}

// Prints:
// type: UIView
// type: String
// type: Integer
// unknown type: Bool
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can limit the objects to subclasses of NSObject then this should work:

```
import Foundation

let array: [AnyObject] = ["hi", true, 12]
let types: [(AnyClass, String)] = [
  (NSString.self, "String"),
  (NSNumber.self, "Number"),
]

for obj in array {
  for (type, name) in types {
    if obj.isKindOfClass( type) {
      println( "type: \(name)")
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure if there is a way to do this with Swift-Only objects.

Comment: The above array is an example. I expect to have another array to check against.